# Hide ?ref string in URL but pass it to script

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

How can I hide ?ref string from users but pass it to php code so it will grab it?

For example, visitor visits this page:

```
http://mysite.com/?ref=ref+string
```

In browser URL I want to hide it, so user will see"

```
http://mysite.com/
```

But I want to grab content of ref string via this:

```
$ref = $_GET['ref'];
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Not while you are using $_GET. You can encode the string to hide it from the user http://mysite.com/?ref=F5858HB22C4GH45HN5H

Comment: Why do you want to hide it? What does it come from?

Comment: @SLaks: it seems to me like he's making a referral script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, if you want to use GET variables, they will always be in the url.

However, you can use an alternative, like $_SESSION or $_POST variables.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this at the top of your PHP script:

```
session_start();

if (isset($_GET['ref'])) {
    $_SESSION['ref'] = $_GET['ref'];
    header('Location: /');
    exit();
}
```

You would have to use `$_SESSION['ref']` to access the value from then on, however.

Answer (score 0):

This is not [how the http protocol works with query strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). If you have information that needs to be in the query string that you want to hide or obfuscate from the user, I would recommend a simple encryption to change it. If you're attempting to get rid of this information for aesthetic reasons, you will need to pursue a different method of generating the header or storing the information (session/cookies/etc).